# How to remotely debug the webapplication running on tomcat service?

Tags: java, tomcat6

I have my webapplication on `tomcat 6` at serverA. I am running the `tomcat` as service i.e thru `tomcat6w.exe` lying under `<tomcat_home>/bin` folder. To remotely debug the
weabbplication i have added below lines as suggested on different blog/sites on web in different line witout space at end. Mentioned the port as 8443 as application is running on same port.

```
-Xdebug-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8443,server=y,suspend=n
```

Now thru `eclipse` on server B i mentioned host as serverA and port 8443 and click debug. After 2-3 minutes it establishes connection without giving any error.But now
when i hit webapplication url in `IE` it does not show up and says `IE` can not display the webpage. But as soon as i remove the above mentioned debug parameters
and hit the url, application works fine. I am not getting how should i debug the application when tomcat is running as window service?

For Information Below are the parameters when i double click the tomcat service

```
--   Under java tab 
--jvm section value  
 C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll

--java classpath section value  
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\bin\bootstrap.jar

--java options section value  
 -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
 -Dcatalina.base=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0
 -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\common endorsed
 -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\temp
 -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
 -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Program Files\Apache Software 
  Foundation\Tomcat6.0\conf\logging.properties-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=c:/.keystore
 -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit-Xdebug 
 -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8443,server=y,suspend=n  

--Under startup tab

--class section value  
org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap

--workingpath section value  
 C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0

--arguments section value  
 start

--mode section value  
 jvm
```

Answer (score 6):

In the Java Options tab add the below. Remember to put

```
-Xdebug
```

and

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8733
```

in **SEPARATE LINE**.

```
-Xdebug
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8733
```

Comment: While this is correct, it does nothing to dispel the questioner's confusion. Some more detail on why this works, and what to do next would be useful.

Comment: If you've installed tomcat as a windows service then right click the Tomcat6w.exe and "run as administrator" Then on the Java tab look for Java Options. That's where you add the two lines.

Answer (score 1):

you can pass JVM options using *JvmOptions* parameter:

```
tomcat.exe //TS// ++JvmOptions -Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

or

```
tomcat.exe //RS// ++JvmOptions -Xdebug;-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=1044
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need to remotely debug an application that is deployed on Tomcat, I usually start the server through the Catalina.bat script, not as a Windows service. Actually, to enable remote debugging, you're supposed to provide the JPDA arguments when executing the catalina.bat script :

> catalina jpda start

If you really need to start your server as a service, you could try to edit its definition so that you also provide the JPDA argument to it.

Yo could as well stop your Tomcat service and just start the server by executing the catalina.bat script.

Hope that'll help.

Comment: weird... you mean I cannot remote-debug as application that deployed on tomcat that runs as a service?

Comment: I've tried a couple of times and did search on the matter but did not find how...