# Debug J2EE Applications on IntelliJ Community Edition and Tomcat8 (running as a service)

Tags: windows, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea, remote-debugging

I've searched a lot on Remote Debugging a REST APIs written in Java using IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition.

My Setup:

Windows 10
Tomcat installed as a windows service
Java 8
Intellij Community IDE

Finally after some googling and sifting through SO, found a solution that works. Posting it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Part I. Running Tomcat in Debug Mode**

When running Tomcat8 as a service

1. Open `{$TOMCAT_HOME}\bin\Tomcat8w.exe`
2. Under `Java > Java Options` add the following lines to enable the debug port 8001:

> ```
> -Xdebug
> -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8001
> ```

3. Restart the Tomcat Service

**Part II. Attaching IntelliJ IDEA Remote Debugger**

1. Create a new Run Configuration using the `Remote` Template.
2. Under `Configuration > Settings` Change the `Port` to 8001
3. Run the new config by clicking on the debug icon and IDEA will connect to the debug port of Tomcat

**Credits:**

1. [How to remotely debug the webapplication running on tomcat service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10221429/how-to-remotely-debug-the-webapplication-running-on-tomcat-service)

Comment: `Tomcat8w.exe`? This is binary. Did you mean `startup.bat` (`startup.sh` for linux)?

Comment: @lealceldeiro, I had posted a windows-y solution (that involved a GUI) to solve this problem in tomcat installations as a windows service. The help regarding this was hard to find at that point in time.